# Should I dispose child session in NHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate

So in my post insert action I need to insert audit entity:

```
public void OnPostInsert(PostInsertEvent e)
{
   var childSession = session.GetSession(EntityMode.Poco);

   childSession.Save(logEntry);
   childSession.Flush();      
}
```

Question is, if I need to dispose childSession or root session is taking care of this?

Answer (score 0):

You should dispose your child sessions just like you would any other session.

Comment: Some time passed since I've posted this question, problem with disposing child sessions is, that they dispose parent session also.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at NH Code, the session disposes its children when it is disposed. So it wouldn't be required.

I don't know why you think that the parent session gets disposed when disposing the child, I cannot see something like this in code. May be it disposes something that is used in common.